# Perl File::Find::Rule excluding directories from an array

Tags: perl, find, file-find

I have a set of directories in an array as

```
chdir /tmp;
my @dir=("test" "abc" "def")
```

I am looking for a way using File::Find::Rule to find all files in /tmp **recursively**, but excluding files from the ones in @dir.

I could get all files from @dir by

```
my $rule =  File::Find::Rule->new;
$rule->file;
my @files = $rule->in( @dir );
```

But I cannot negate the condition, that is to exclude @dir. I was trying

```
chdir /tmp;
@files = File::Find::Rule->new
    ->file()
    ->name(@dir)
    ->prune
    ->in( "." );
```

but no output.

Comment: Your examples are not working because they are not valid Perl code. Please fix the syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) lists this example:

> ignore CVS directories
>
> ```
> my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new; $rule->or($rule->new
>                ->directory
>                ->name('CVS')
>                ->prune
>                ->discard,
>           $rule->new);
> ```
>
> Note here the use of a null rule. Null rules match anything they see, so the effect is to match (and discard) directories called 'CVS' or to match anything

You could probalby do the same thing:

```
my @exclude_dirs = qw(test abc def);
my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new; 
$rule->or($rule->new
               ->directory
               ->name(@exclude_dirs)
               ->prune
               ->discard,
          $rule->new);
my @files = $rule->in('/tmp');
```

---

Consider this example:

```
foo@bar:~/temp/filefind> tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── bar.txt
│   └── foobar.txt
├── baz.txt
└── foo
    └── foo.txt

2 directories, 4 files
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strictures;
use File::Find::Rule;
use Data::Dump;

my @exclude_dirs = qw(foo);
my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new; 
$rule->or($rule->new
               ->directory
               ->name(@exclude_dirs)
               ->prune
               ->discard,
          $rule->new);
my @files = $rule->in('filefind');
dd \@files;
```

And now I run this:

```
foo@bar:~/temp> perl file-find.pl
[
  "filefind",
  "filefind/baz.txt",
  "filefind/bar",
  "filefind/bar/bar.txt",
  "filefind/bar/foobar.txt",
]
```

Comment: I tried the same initially, after refering the documentation, but that was giving empty output as well. Tried the list of directories as an array, and as a space separated string, but both didn't work.

Comment: Just tried it. It's working for me with folders in my file system.

Comment: Got the error. I re-defined a my variable inside that subroutine, which I declared and used before. Thank you simbabque.