# Exclude specific directory in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to write code to read all the files present in a directory  except a specific directory.

Directory path:

```
constellation/netcool/aws_netcool_db2/trunk/src
```

Under `src`, there are 3 directories (`base` , `v1_version`, `v2_version`, `v3_version`). I want to read all directory except `base` directory.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Being a new SO user, I'll suggest you to please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it helps others and in turn they can help you back.

Comment: See also [Excluding certain directories with Find::File::Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25008883/2173773) and [Perl File::Find::Rule excluding directories from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21431191/2173773) and [File::Find::Rule to exclude a single dir only for the top level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25895751/2173773)

Answer (score 0):

Using `find`:

```
quotemeta() { printf '%s' "$1" | perl -0777ne'print quotemeta($_)'; }

path=constellation/netcool/aws_netcool_db2/trunk/src

find "$path" \
   -path "$( quotemeta "$path/base" )" \
   -prune \
-o \
   \! -type d \
   -print
```

Note that this doesn't work for paths starting with `-`. Prepend `./` to those.

---

Using Perl:

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

my $path = "constellation/netcool/aws_netcool_db2/trunk/src";

my $FFR = File::Find::Rule::;
my @files =
   $FFR->or(
      $FFR
         ->exec(sub{ $_[2] eq "$path/base" })
         ->prune
         ->discard,
      $FFR
         ->not( $FFR->directory ),
   )
      ->in($path);
```

Note that this doesn't work for all paths (e.g. `.`, those that end with `/`, etc) because F::F::R cleans up the paths. You would need to apply those same undocumented cleanups to the value against which `$_[2]` is compared if you wish to support arbitrary paths.

Comment: It worked exactly the way I wanted. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: The output contains the directories too.


/opt/IBM/tivoli/netcool/AWS/DB2/sql_scripts /opt/IBM/tivoli/netcool/AWS/DB2/sql_scripts/v2_version /opt/IBM/tivoli/netcool/AWS/DB2/sql_scripts/v2_version/Rollback.sql /opt/IBM/tivoli/netcool/AWS/DB2/sql_scripts/v2_version/UpdateSchemaVersionHistory.sql /opt/IBM/tivoli/netcool/AWS/DB2/sql_scripts/v1_version /opt/IBM/tivoli/netcool/AWS/DB2/sql_scripts/v1_version/Rollback.sql /opt/IBM/tivoli/netcool/AWS/DB2/sql_scripts/v1_version/UpdateSchemaVersionHistory.sql 



How Can I get only file names?